# Chaining non overlaping, non-contiguous iterators in c++ (/boost)

Tags: c++, boost

(Caveat: I'm a beginner in `C++`).

Consider this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

template<class RandomAccessIterator1>
typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator1>::value_type
foo(RandomAccessIterator1 firsta,RandomAccessIterator1 lasta,float store[]){
    const float x1=*firsta;

    int i=0;
    for (RandomAccessIterator1 it=firsta;it!=lasta+1;it++){
            store[i++]=x1-*it;
    }
    return(*(firsta+3));
}
int main(){
    const int n=*nr;
    int i;
    float x[n],store[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)    x[i]=(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    std::sort(x,x+n);
    float a2=(x[1]+x[n-1])*0.5f;
    int m0=std::upper_bound(x,x+n,a2)-x; 
    int m1=m0/2-1;
    float var=foo(x,x+m0,store);    
    for(i=0;i<m0-1;i++) std::cout<< store[i] << std::endl;
}
```

My problem is that I need `foo` to *not* take `x[m1]` into account. Simply 'forget' that element as it were. But I don't really have access to the real `foo` itself: everything has to be done on the level of the inputs to `foo`, not the function itself. In other word, I need to somehow make `firsta,lasta` the bounds of 
an `RandomAccessIterator` that contains all the elements in the range `[firsta,lasta)` *except* the `m1`-th. I don't have anything against using boost or other external 
open source libraries. My only problem is that whatever solution should be `O(1)`. 
Oh, and I don't even know if it is possible.

I put the tag `boost` because there seems to be a [series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981186/chain-iterator-for-c) of related question on SO that solve this problem using `boost`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do anything in foo that only really leaves you with the option of copying everything but the m1-th value into a vector (or some other random access container).

Comment: Thanks. That's what I feared. I will let the question open a little more to see if there is any hope.

Comment: I guess you could also write your own iterator to skip the necessary value EDIT: as IronMensan has just posted!

Comment: thanks, bbut I don't see how that would work in practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new iterator class that knows about values to skip.  Something that looks roughly like this:

```
class MyIterator
{
public:
    MyIterator(containerClass & myContainer, value_type valueToSkip);
private:
    containerClass::iterator baseIterator;
    value_type skipValue;
};
```

Obviously I've left out a lot of the details.

Comment: is there a way you could make this self-contained e.g. usable? Basically your just sayin' 'its possible but it's gonna be complicated'...Which is an improvement over the other answer...I don't really see the point of your code.

Comment: I left out most of the details because I didn't think it would be complicated to fill them in.