# iterator over multiple std containers subsequently

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

I have the following class (which obviously does not yet work as intended):

```
class A
{
private:
    std::vector<int> firstVector, secondVector;
public:
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin(){
        return firstVector.begin();
    }
    std::vector<int>::iterator end(){
        return secondVector.end();
    }
};
```

How can I define an iterator which will go over the two member containers subsequently, e.g. after `firstVector.end()-1` `secondVector.begin()` is returned and going all the way to `secondVector.end()` ?

Comment: An iterator is also just a normal class type, so go and write your own. You could also check out Boost.Iterator, which is a utility library to facilitate writing iterators.

Comment: You need to define a custom `iterator`.

Comment: how would you make a C pointer do it ? an iterator just wrap it around with more protections and methods. you need to implement ti yourself, eg. when the iterator == firstvector.end jump to secondVector.begin()

Comment: This question is quite a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981186/chain-iterator-for-c But since this is a special case of only two ranges to chain, it's at least possible that the answer is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to stop you from rolling your own. Can even make it random access!

```
struct chain_iterator 
    : std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, int>
{
    using it = std::vector<int>::iterator;

    std::pair<it, it> v1, v2;
    bool first;
    it cur;
};
```

We keep the initial iterator pairs so that we can do random access correctly.

Incrementing is what you'd expect:

```
chain_iterator& operator++() {
    ++cur;
    if (first && cur == v1.second) {
        first = false;
        cur = v2.first;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Dereference is trivial:

```
int& operator*() { return *cur; }
```

Advance has to do some extra checking:

```
chain_iterator& operator+=(size_t n) {
    if (!first) {
        // trivial case
        cur += n;
    }
    else {
        size_t d = v1.second - cur;
        if (d < n) {
            cur += n;
        }
        else {
            first = false;
            cur = v2.first + (d - n);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I'll leave the rest of the operations as an exercise.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you need to define some custom iterator that internally checks for the end of the first range, then goes on to the next one.

However, this sort of stuff occurs a lot. Eventually you'd ask why an iterator for *two* vectors, why an iterator for two *vectors*, why a sequence of the same container type, and so on. Nir Tzachar & I have written a [C++ port of Python itertools](http://cpp_itertools_range.bitbucket.org/group__chain.html) that does this sort of common stuff. In this case, you'd just use

```
chain(firstVector, secondVector)
```

It can be downloaded from [this bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/cpp_itertools_range/cpp_itertools_range).

Answer (score -2):

You could write your own function to do the incrementing:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator& inc(std::vector<int>::iterator& it) {
    ++it;
    if (it == firstVector.end())
        it = secondVector.begin();
    return it;
}
```

This is also a good indication to others that the increment doesn't happen normally.

Comment: "the increment doesn't happen normally" -- and that usual RandomAccessIterator operations like `<` and binary `+` don't work across the whole range!