# How to iterate over few containers in sequence?

Tags: c++, loops, boost, iterator, containers

Having similar piece of code to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v1, v2;
  for (const auto& s : v1) {
    // do something with s
  }
  for (const auto& s : v2) {
    // do something with s
  }
}
```

I would like to iterate over all elements from `v1` and `v2` in one go (and since the logic is kind of difficult in those loops I cannot use functions inside them - for the sake of this question).

So the ideal solution would be something like:

```
  for (const auto& s : magic(v1,v2)) {
    // do something with s
  }
```

obviously without allocating new container with all elements copied to it (since that solution is trivial.

Is there anything like it e.g. in `boost`?

Comment: Boost range FTW: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981186/chain-iterator-for-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
const std::vector<std::string> v1{"A", "B", "C"}, v2{"D", "E", "F"};

for (const auto& s : ranges::view::concat(v1, v2)) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;   
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53ee33b2df6a6e57)

Comment: I had no idea that http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com has `range-v3` o.0

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses an [*higher-order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function):

```
template <typename TC0, typename TC1, typename TF>
void forJoined(TC0&& c0, TC1&& c1, TF&& f)
{
    for(auto&& x : c0) f(x);
    for(auto&& x : c1) f(x);
}
```

You can use `forJoined` as follows:

```
std::vector<int> a{0, 1, 2};
std::vector<char> b{'a', 'b', 'c'};

forJoined(a, b, [](auto x){ std::cout << x; });
// Will print "012abc".
```

As you can see `forJoined` will also work when your containers are storing elements of different types. Using a template parameter to pass `f` introduces no extra overhead *([see my latest article on the subject](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html))*.

You can extend this to an arbitrary number of containers by  using a [*variadic template*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an initializer list. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <functional>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v1 = { "A", "B", "C" };
    std::vector<std::string> v2 = { "X", "Y", "Z" };

    for ( const auto &r : { std::cref( v1 ), std::cref( v2 ) } )
    {
        for ( const auto &s : r.get() ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
A B C X Y Z
```