# Iterate over vector of vectors with one iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

Suppose I have a

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > vvi;
```

I want to hide the fact that `vvi` is a vector of vectors, and create an iterator over all its contained `int` elements, like:

```
class vvi_iterator; // Iterator over std::vector< std::vector< int > >
                    // I am looking for a template of such class, 
                    // or I would need to implement it on my own.

vvi_iterator itBegin = make_vvi_iterator_begin( vvi );  // helper function
                                // that creates a vvi_iterator pointing to the 
                                // first element of the first vector

vvi_iterator itEnd   = make_vvi_iterator_end( vvi ); // helper function
                                // that creates a vvi_iterator in the "end" state
                                // (e.g. pointing behind the last element of the 
                                // last vector)


// This is how I'm going to use it:

auto itRange = boost::iterator_range<vvi_iterator>( itBegin, itEnd );

for( int& i : itRange ) {
   doSomething(i);
}
```

I don't need to insert/erase `int` elements.

I can use `boost`, as well as other external libraries.

I can use `C++11`, but not `c++14`. Yet, solutions  involving `c++14` would also be interesting.

Thanks in advance.

.

.

**UPD.:** Folded loops don't work for me. In my real use case I have

```
class A {
private:
    std::array< std::unordered_map< std::unique_ptr< SomeDataClass > > > _own_data;
}

class B {
private:
    std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< SomeDataClass > > _referenced_data;
}
```

and I need to pass reference**s** to all `SomeDataClass` objects from `A`, as well as from `B`, to some other class `X`. I don't want class `X` to know about the internal structure of `A` and `B`, and I don't want to treat them separately.

If I did not have folded containers, I could have used `boost::indirect_iterator`:

```
class A {
private:
    std::array< std::unique_ptr< SomeDataClass > > _own_data;

public:
    boost::iterator_range< 
        boost::indirect_iterator<
            std::array< std::unique_ptr< SomeDataClass> >::iterator > >
    getSomeData() {
        return { boost::make_indirect_iterator( _own_data.begin() ),
                 boost::make_indirect_iterator( _own_data.end()   ) }
    }
}

class X {
private:
    doSomething( SomeDataClass& someData );

public:
    template<typename IteratorRangeType>
    processSomeData( IteratorRangeType itRange ) {
        for( auto& someData : itRange ) {
            doSomething( someData ); 
        }
    }
}



int main(int, char**) {
    A a;
    X x;
    x.processsSomeData( a.getSomeData() ); // isn't it beautiful? 
}
```

Now, I hope there exists something like `folded_container_iterator`, and I hope I can combine it with the `boost::indirect_iterator` and `boost_iterator_range`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/981186/1025391

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [Flattening iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3623082/335858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterator for 2d vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784573/iterator-for-2d-vector)

Comment: If the number of elements in the inner `vector`s is the same for all of them, I would prefer to use a 2D adaptation of a single underlying `vector` holding all the data. Then you can still use a single iterator over the underlying `vector`, but also access the data via the 2D adaptor. Moreover, the memory management is much simplified (only one call to `new int[]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do

```
std::vector< std::vector< int > > v /* = ...*/;

for (auto e : v | ranges::view::join) {
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c18d787c422b731)